# load a div with custdata

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, onclick

I am loading a tr onclick the first tr but the problem is each td in the tr should load the different div which is inside the second div. Now the content which is inside the custdata is loading but how do I load the content which is inside the respective div??

Here is the demo
http://jsfiddle.net/FMnTa/6/

Comment: I recommend adding some punctuation in your post to make it more comprehensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you are asking for, but it seems like it.

```
$(function(){
    $(".info").find("img").click(function(){                
        var trid = $(this).parent().attr("idcust");                
        var trdata = $(this).parent().attr("custdata");
        // Hide all content divs and show only the one related to the click
        $("#"+trid).children().hide();
        $(trdata).show();
        $("#"+trid).css("display","block");
    });
});​
```

**Here is a fiddle as well:** http://jsfiddle.net/FMnTa/9/

The code could also be somewhat improved like this:

```
$(function(){
    $("img", ".info").click(function(){                
        var parent = $(this).parent();
        var trid = parent.attr("idcust");                
        var trdata = parent.attr("custdata");
        // Hide all content divs and show only the one related to the click
        $("#"+trid).show().children().hide();
        $(trdata).show();
    });
});​
```

**Custom data attributes**

When using custom attributes, you should really consider using the [custom data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Global_attributes) (`data-` attributes) instead. In your case the attributes would be `data-idcust` and `data-custdata`.

You could then use jQuery's [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to get/set the attributes. Given that you name the attribute `data-idcust` you could read it with `.data("custid")` and set it with `.data("custid", "newValue")`.

Comment: Thank you.. This is wat i was looking for. But one more thing is, why is that green td is taking small space it should cover the entire tr right? Any idea?? Also if I click on the same icon second time then it should hide the content tr

Comment: @Sowmya Alright, it is sorted out in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FMnTa/12/). Notice that I added an additional CSS rule at then end of the CSS as well, that you need in order for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

See what happen with this:

```
   $(".info").find("img").click(function(){                
        var trid = $(this).parent().attr("idcust");                
        var trdata = $(this).parent().attr("custdata");
        $("#"+trid).show().find(trdata).css('border', '1px solid red');
        $("#"+trid).show().find(trdata).toggle();
    });
```

`find(trdata)` find the `tr1 div` with `id trdata`